# Batch move with exceptions? Or using xcopy and deleting original after?

Tags: batch-file, move, xcopy, file-organization

I have a script that extracts all files from all sub-directories and deletes the empty sub-directories afterwards, the part that extracts reads:

```
for /r %%a in (*.*) do move "%%a" "%~dp0"
```

Is there a way to do this with the exception of sub-directories named "_Unsorted"?  I know xcopy has an `/exclude` option, so something like

```
for /r %%a in (*.*) do xcopy "%%a" "%~dp0" /exclude "\_Unsorted\"
```

would almost work, but I'm not sure how to delete the original after it's copied to essentially have the same result as `move`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some batch-only options:

1. Add a filter into the loop body:

   ```
   for /r %%a in (*.*) do (
     (echo %%~dpa | find /i "\_Unsorted\" 1>nul) || move "%%a" "%~dp0"
   )
   ```

   Alternatively:

   ```
   for /r %%a in (*.*) do (
     (echo %%~dpa | find /i /v "\_Unsorted\" 1>nul) && move "%%a" "%~dp0"
   )
   ```

   In both versions, the `find` command is used to match the file's path against the substring `\_Unsorted\`. In the first version, `find` returns `success` if there is a match and `fail` otherwise. The `move` command is called only in case of `fail`, which is the effect of the `||` operator`.

   In the second version, the `/v` switch reverses the result of `find` and `success` now means *no* match. Accordingly, the `&&` operator is used to call `move` in case of `success`.
2. Apply the filter to the file list, so that the loop never iterates over `_Unsorted` entries.

   ```
   for /f "delims=" %%a in (
     'dir /s /b ^| find /i /v "\_Unsorted\"'
   ) do move "%%a" "%~dp0"
   ```

   This is a more essential change to the original script than the previous option, as this replaces the `for /r` loop with a `for /f` one.

   Basically, a `for /f` loop is used to read/parse a piece of text, a text file or a command's output. In this case, the `dir` command provides a complete list of files in the current directory's tree and the `find` command filters out those containing `\_Unsorted\` in their paths. The `for /f` loop reads the list after it's been filtered down by `find`, which means it never hits files stored in `_Unsorted` (sub)folders.

Comment: Looks promising, but they don't seem to work.  The first two options extract the files from '\_Unsorted\' anyways and the latter option doesn't run.  Any idea?

Comment: There were mistakes in all of them (the facepalm kind ones). Please take a look now.

Comment: They work perfectly, thanks.  Are any of these options inherently better than the others?  Or is it up to personal preference as a programmer?  I'm pretty new to this, trying to teach myself python and batch scripting concurrently.

Comment: I haven't done proper testing. My personal opinion is the #2 would probably be better than either of the #1 variations. The filtering is more or less the same in both cases, but #2 filters all the items in one go, which must be faster then testing every item individually. And, because the list of items is cut down *before* the loop starts, #2 performs fewer iterations too. On the other hand, of course, iterating over files in a directory tree may be more efficient than iterating over lines of a command's output, but I'm not sure to what extent that would counterbalance the performance.

Answer (score 3):

Can you use robocopy?

```
robocopy from\path to\path *.* /mov /e /xd _Unsorted
```

`/mov`:  move rather than copy (delete the source after copying)

`/e`:  recursive (including empty subdirectories)

`/xd _Unsorted`:  exclude directories named _Unsorted

Comment: Hopefully, the OP uses a Windows version that has `robocopy`, although this powerful tool is worth mentioning either way.

Answer (score 0):

Answer 3 above, using ROBOCOPY, creates a tree of (possibly empty) subdirectories.

The following requires the obtaining of xxcopy

```
xxcopy c:\filematch d:\dest\ /SGF /RC
```

copies from c: to folder d:\dest

/SGF recurses subdirectories but flattens the result at the destination.
In the event of filename collision, it appends .0001 to the first duplicate filename. So /SGF copies every matching file from the source drive, no matter what subdirectory it occupies, into a specified destination folder.

/RC removes the files from the source following a successful copy, AKA it moves them.

Not sure if it is what the OP wanted, but this discussion helped me!